# iOS 9 Safari Web App links open in Safari

Tags: ios, mobile, web, web-applications, safari

I have a mobile web app capable safari app for iPhone running on iOS 9. There's only one problem: the fix for opening links IN the mobile web app, doesn't seem to work anymore.

I have this code as a fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('noeffect')) {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

But still my links are opening in a separate safari window, in stead of in the web app itself.

Working demo can be seen at: http://www.dennisprins.nl/project6, when you hit the "Toevoegen"-dashed box, you'll see what happens when you added the page to your homescreen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aagh! I've got a web app in production, and haven't checked it on iOS 9 yet. I'm updating my iPhone now so I can check Apple haven't dug a hole for me... Will let you know if I have the same problem and/or find a solution.

Comment: Hmm, my web app still works fine! It uses the same basic technique as yours, so I'm not sure why yours no longer works. It is running after the page has loaded, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <script>
    (function(document,navigator,standalone) {
        // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
        // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
        if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
            var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                curnode=e.target;
                while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                    curnode=curnode.parentNode;
                }
                // Conditions to do this only on links to your own app
                // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
                if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    location.href = curnode.href;
                }
            },false);
        }
    })(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
</script>
```